# Get public ip in raspbian and upload it to dropbox, pastebin or whatever

Tags: server, raspberry-pi, ip, minecraft, raspbian

I'm trying to get my public ip with a periodic script in raspbian, for my personal multimedia server and minecraft server, so when it changes, i can go to dropbox, pastebin or whatever service, and read the new public ip of my home.

I don't wanna disturb anybody (web services, google, myip.xx, etc) with constants pings or anything.

If it is possible, i would like to do it with with no gui, cause i would like to run rasbian without gui.

Thanks

Comment: Did you consider using a free dns provider in order to work with the URL instead of the IP directly? You can find a list of different clients that run in the background in order to update the current IP [here](https://freedns.afraid.org/scripts/freedns.clients.php).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest helios35 solution, too. However if you want to find out your public IP from the command line, this should do the trick:

```
curl http://ipecho.net/plain
```